# Is there a way for a java chat client program to dynamically find the host server?

Tags: java, client-server, chat

I want to just execute an instance of *client* with no parameters other than the port number and have the program find the server listening on that port anywhere on the network.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UDP multi-cast to find the server.  You can send a UDP packet to the port and have the server respond with its IP address. (This effectively hard codes a multi-cast address) which is not much better than hardcoding a hostname which can be looked up via DNS.

Comment: Thanx, Peter. I have code to do exactly that...// Gets the IP address of the Server
 address = InetAddress.getByName(args[0]);
 socket = new DatagramSocket();
But as you say, it's not much different than hardcoding the hostname. Also, I was trying to keep it as TCP/IP

Comment: TCP/IP has to have a hostname or IP address.  I suggest you use DNS or some domain name lookup.